# Angular 8 ngIf creates empty element when false

Tags: html, angular, angular-ng-if

I have a problem with Anguar8 and ngIf:

I have a code that creates div which loads some images and their details to a page from a json with conditon:

HTML Code:

```
        <div class="row" >
          <div class="col-md-2 col-6 col-sm-4" style="margin-bottom: 1em;" *ngFor="let item of product; let i=index"> <br>
            <div class="box" *ngIf="i>35">
              <img [src]="item.photo" alt="image slide" style="display: block; width: 100%;">
              <div class="text-center">
                <h6>{{item.name}}</h6>
                <h6>MRP : ₹ {{item.price}}</h6>                
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

The problem is, that angular creates an empty div with this comment in it:

```
<div _ngcontent-oio-c3="" class="col-md-2 col-6 col-sm-4" style="margin-bottom: 1em;"><br _ngcontent-oio-c3=""><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--></div>
```

Comment: This is behaving as expected. The div which has ngif is not created but it’s parents are present in the HTML.

Comment: The div will be shown as it is outer div, and it is the expected behaviour.

Comment: Check this url https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe. You can use slice pipe. Let me know if you face any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may write `*ngFor="let item of product | slice:0:35;"`.
Reference https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe

Answer (score 0):

**There are two options:**
1.You can filter the list using pipe to avoid 
2.You can try this should not create any template

```html
<div *ngIf="i>35; else noData">
 {{data}}
</div>
<ng-template #noData>
</ng-template>
```